# Thread "run twice" in android when resume

Tags: android, multithreading

I have really wired problem..I searced a lot in google and here and con't solve my problem.
I have main activity which create and start 3 threads (only "gameThread" is relevant now).

When I click on the back buttom it seems ok , but when I come back to the activity and the thread continue running , it seems it run duplicate - I see only one ContentView on the screen, but there is more one running (maybe behind).
I hope I explain myselg good..

this is the code:

```
package com.example.newpingpong;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * The main activity class of the Ping Pong game
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /*
     * The following class variables hold references to the objects the game is composed of -
     * PingPongView - main view,
     * gameBall - the ball in the game,
     * gamePaddle - the paddle in the game,
     * gameThread - main thread updating the position of the ball,
     * paddleMoverThread - another thread which is responsible for moving the paddle.
     */
    private PingPongView gameView;
    private Tray gamePaddle;
    private GameLevel gameLevel;


    private GameLevel [] levels;



    //threads
    private PingPongGame gameThread;
    private PaddleMover paddleMoverThread;
    private PresentThread giftThread;

    private Messages message;

    //balls container
    private BallView [] ballViewArr;
    private Ball     [] ballArr;

    //gifts container
    private Gift[] giftArr;
    private GiftView[] GiftViewArr;

    public GameSounds gameSounds;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;
    private TrayView paddleView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String levelChosed = intent.getStringExtra(ImageAdapter.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        int levelChosed_int = Integer.parseInt(levelChosed);

        Const.currentLevel = levelChosed_int;
        Const.isCompleteThisLevel = false;


        GameLevelView gameLevelView;

        //for sounds
        if(gameSounds == null){
        gameSounds = new GameSounds();

        gameSounds.addSound(Const.CATCH_GIFT, R.raw.cathc_gift, getBaseContext());
        gameSounds.addSound(Const.GIFT_START_FALL, R.raw.gift_start_fall, getBaseContext());
        gameSounds.addSound(Const.HIT_BLOCK, R.raw.hit_block, getBaseContext());
        gameSounds.addSound(Const.HIT_KIR, R.raw.hit_kir, getBaseContext());
        gameSounds.addSound(Const.GAME_OVER, R.raw.game_over, getBaseContext());
        gameSounds.addSound(Const.HIT_PADDLE, R.raw.hit_paddle, getBaseContext());
        }


if(this.ballViewArr == null){
        this.ballViewArr = new BallView[Const.MAX_BALLS];
        this.ballArr = new Ball[Const.MAX_BALLS];

        this.giftArr = new Gift[Const.MAX_GIFTS];
        this.GiftViewArr = new GiftView[Const.MAX_GIFTS];;



        // Getting the screen width & height
        screenWidth = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        for(int i=0 ; i< Const.MAX_BALLS ; i++){
            this.ballArr[i] =  new Ball(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            this.ballViewArr[i] = new BallView(this, this.ballArr[i]);
            this.ballArr[i].setMode(Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
        }
        this.ballArr[0].setMode(Const.ACTIVE);

        for(int i=0 ; i< Const.MAX_GIFTS ; i++){
            this.giftArr[i] =  new Gift(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 4,screenWidth, null, Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
            this.GiftViewArr[i] = new GiftView(this, this.giftArr[i]);
        }


        // Creating the paddle
        gamePaddle = new Tray(screenWidth / 2, (int)(screenHeight * 0.75), screenWidth);

        // Creating the paddle view, and giving it the gameBall as a parameter
        paddleView = new TrayView(this, gamePaddle);



        levels = new GameLevel[Const.LevelsAmount];



        levels[0] = new GameLevel(Const.level0, screenWidth , screenHeight, this.giftArr);
        levels[1] = new GameLevel(Const.level1, screenWidth , screenHeight, this.giftArr);
        levels[2] = new GameLevel(Const.level2,screenWidth , screenHeight, this.giftArr);

}
        gameLevel=levels[levelChosed_int];
        gameLevelView = new GameLevelView(this,gameLevel);

        // Creating the game view
        this.gameView = new PingPongView(this);
        message = new Messages(this , screenWidth , screenHeight);
        // Give the gameView our ballView & paddleView.
        gameView.setViews(paddleView,gameLevelView , message ,this.ballViewArr , this.GiftViewArr);

        // Setting the gameView as the main view for the PingPong activity.
        setContentView(gameView);

        if(gameThread == null){
            //create the main thread
            gameThread = new PingPongGame(this.getResources(), gamePaddle, gameView, gameLevel , message , ballArr , gameSounds);

            //create the thread responsible for moving the paddle
            paddleMoverThread = new PaddleMover(gamePaddle, gameView);

            //create the thread responsible for present
            giftThread = new  PresentThread(gamePaddle , gameView , gameLevel, message ,  giftArr , ballArr,gameSounds );


            gameThread.start();
            paddleMoverThread.start();
            giftThread.start();

    }    
    }


    //This method is automatically called when the user touches the screen
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float destination;
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "try!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //get the x coordinate of users' press
        destination = event.getX();

        //notify the paddle mover thread regarding the new destination
        gamePaddle.setPaddleDestination(destination);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onPause!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Const.toStop = true;
        while(Const.toStopMessageHasRecieved == false){
        } //the thread not see the message that he shoult stop
        //here the thrad recived the message and stoped.
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onResume!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for(int i=0 ; i< Const.MAX_BALLS ; i++){
            this.ballArr[i] =  new Ball(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            this.ballViewArr[i] = new BallView(this, this.ballArr[i]);
            this.ballArr[i].setMode(Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
        }
        this.ballArr[0].setMode(Const.ACTIVE);


        synchronized (Const.mPauseLock) {
            Const.toStop = false;
            Const.mPauseLock.notifyAll();

        }
        super.onResume();       
    }

}
```

AND THE THREAD:

```
package com.example.newpingpong;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;


public class PingPongGame extends Thread {

    private PingPongView gameView;
    private Tray gamePaddle;
    private GameLevel gameLevel;
    private Messages message;
    private Ball [] ballArr;
    private GameSounds gameSounds;



    private Resources res;


    //private int screenWidth;
    //private int screenHight;


    public PingPongGame(Resources res ,Tray theTray , PingPongView mainView , GameLevel gameLevel , 
            Messages message , Ball ballArr[] ,GameSounds gameSounds)
    {
        this.gameView = mainView;
        this.ballArr = ballArr;
        this.gamePaddle = theTray;
        this.gameLevel=gameLevel;
        this.message = message;
        this.gameSounds=gameSounds;

        this.res=res;
        //this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        //this.screenHight = screenHight;
        //for stop and resume threads



    }

    //main method of the current thread
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            PingPongGame.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.message.setMessage(res.getString(R.string.lives) + gameLevel.getLives());
        gameView.postInvalidate();

        //infinitely loop, and move the balls accordingly
        while ((Const.isLose == false) && (Const.isCompleteThisLevel==false))
        {

            for(int i=0; i<Const.MAX_BALLS ; i++){
                if(ballArr[i].getMode() != Const.NOT_ACTIVE){

                    //move the ball one step            
                    if(ballArr[i].move()) //hit kir
                        gameSounds.play(Const.HIT_KIR,false);   
                    gameView.postInvalidate();

                    //check if the ball hit some block
                    if(gameLevel.updateIfHit(ballArr[i])){
                        ballArr[i].down();
                        gameSounds.play(Const.HIT_BLOCK,false); 
                    }
                    gameView.postInvalidate();


                    if(gameLevel.getLives() == 0){
                        //gameLevel.restart();
                        this.message.setMessage(res.getString(R.string.game_over));
                        gameView.postInvalidate();
                        gameSounds.play(Const.GAME_OVER,false); 
                        Const.isLose = true;
                        try
                        {
                            PingPongGame.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    //check if the ball has reached the paddle
                    if(checkHitPaddle(i,ballArr[i]) == true){ //משתמש פספס  and  lives --
                        this.message.setMessage(res.getString(R.string.lives)+"" + gameLevel.getLives());
                        //send a request to refresh the display
                        gameView.postInvalidate();

                    }
                }
            }
                try
            {
                PingPongGame.sleep(5);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                //public static boolean toStop = false;
                //public static boolean toStopMessageHasRecieved = false;
                //for stop and resume
                //for stop and resume
                synchronized (Const.mPauseLock) {
                    while (Const.toStop) {
                        Const.toStopMessageHasRecieved = true;
                        try {
                            Const.mPauseLock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }

        }

    //  Const.toStopMessageHasRecieved = true;
    }



    //This method is responsible for handling the situation in which the ball has reached the height of the paddle
    //return true if lives--
    private boolean checkHitPaddle(int i , Ball ball)
    {
        // Checking if the ball had hit the paddle
        if (ball.getBottom() >= gamePaddle.getTop())
        {
            // check if the paddle is in the right place
            if ((ball.getRight() > gamePaddle.getLeft()) &&
                    (ball.getLeft() < gamePaddle.getRight()))
            {
                //The ball had hit the paddle - so it should be bounced
                gameSounds.play(Const.HIT_PADDLE,false);    
                ball.bounceUp();

            }
            else
            {
                //The ball had missed the paddle - player looses - restart the game
                gameSounds.play(Const.GAME_OVER,false);  //not really game over - just lose live
                boolean isMoreBall = false;
                for(int j=0 ; j< Const.MAX_BALLS ; j++)
                    if( (j != i) && (ballArr[j].getMode() == Const.ACTIVE)){
                        isMoreBall = true;
                        break;
                    }

                if(isMoreBall){
                    ball.setMode(Const.NOT_ACTIVE);
                    //for(int k=0; k<Const.MAX_BALLS ; k++){
                        //ballArr[k].downSpeed(0.25);
                    //}
                }
                else{
                    gameLevel.setLives(gameLevel.getLives()-1);
                    ball.restart();
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the Activity is started you create a new gameThread in onCreate since the Activity is a new object then and gameThread is null. But you never stop them. You should probably insert something that ends your threads in onDestroy.

At the moment both Threads modify your Const object. Which leads me to the main problem:
I think the main problem is that all your communication is handled by some 'Global Variable Collection' in the Const object which can be very confusing the bigger the game gets. For now a solution could be to let the Const object handle the Threads too, but that would possibly only make it worse on the long run.

Comment: but, as I know , onCreate is calld only when I close the app... or I wrong?

Comment: this is only partly true - it depends on how you leave and how you return to your activity. As well on orientation change onCreate is called again. But you could at least switch the orientation change stuff off in the manifest in the android:configChanges property of your activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
Timer rather than Thread.

And cancel timer using timer.cancel() in onBackPressed() method.